# Indesign: Possible to make a fillable text-field that is automatically also shown in another place on the document (like cross-reference)?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cross-reference

Is it possible to make a fillable text-field that is automatically also shown in another place on a PDF document (like cross-reference)?

ENTER PROJECT CODE (FILLABLE TEXT FIELD):

```
CODE5491
```

AUTOMATICALLY UPDATED FIELD

> CODE5491

Can we do the same with icons (find icon, use in a document, it is shown in many places after its insertion)?

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want this to happen during the design phase in InDesign (which is possible) or if you want this to be something the user can later do in the PDF in Acrobat (which I don't know if is possible).

Comment: Good point. This should happen in the final exported PDF document (not in the design phase).